# How to measure timespan using Process.GetCurrentProcess().Threads[0].UserProcessorTime

Tags: multithreading, c#-4.0, time, process

In order to measure the performance of some code... I am running below code block

```
startingTime = Process.GetCurrentProcess().Threads[0].UserProcessorTime;
<Some lengthy taks>
duration = Process.GetCurrentProcess().Threads[0].UserProcessorTime.Subtract(startingTime);
```

but the problem is duration is always 0(zero).

I cannot use StopWatch as it will include all the time that system spent elsewhere like GC or outside my process.

Can anyone help me to find what's wrong here.

Comment: You should use `StopWatch` to measure elapsed time. `UserProcessorTime` will not include time spent in the kernel (eg. completing API calls) or delays due to blocking for IO.

Comment: How much time is spent in GC is very much part of the performance of your code (garbage is not free). If you are trying to do performance measurement in a context where other things are running – even if there CPU time is factored out – memory and IO overheads of those things will impact your code's performance. Easier to put the effort into a cleaner measuring environment than eliminate externalities.

Comment: The odds that Threads[0] for long-running code is the correct one is never very good.  There is no simple way to match a .NET thread with a ProcessThread, you'd need pinvoke to call GetCurrentThreadId() and match it with ProcessThread.Id.  Which can only be done by tinkering with the threaded code itself, you might as well use Stopwatch instead.

Comment: Thanks guys... I believe, stopwatch is the correct way to measure the time complexity here. I'll it now.